# Get image data for resizableImageWithCapInsets: after being resized

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I have a png that I'm using as an image mask for another image. Both image have rounded corners that are being preserved with resizableImageWithCapInsets:. The image (not the mask) is being sized automatically because it is the progressImage of a UIProgressView.

The problem I'm having is that if I use CGImageMaskCreate to create a mask and simply give it the width of of the width of the UIProgressView, the mask image is being stretched (ie, it does not preserve the caps).

What I'd like to do is create a new UIImage with resizable caps, manually resize the image (perhaps by putting it in a UIImageView), get the data representation of the resized version of the mask image, then create a new image with that data and use that image as the mask. It seems, though, that even if I create a UIImageView with the image, and then set the frame of the UIImageView appropriately, getting the image back out of the view gives my original image.

Is there any way to get the result of a resizableImageWithCapInsets: image without it actually being drawn into the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I would try drawing image piece by piece into CGContext where you can access data provider or extract NSData through creating UIImage

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage*) drawImage:(UIImage *)image
                atSize:(CGSize) size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *outImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outImage;
}
```